Is there any way i can get both Matter and Arcade physic in Player object
I tried to create a player object
export default class Player extends Phaser.Physics.Matter.Sprite {
    constructor(data) {
        let { scene, x, y, texture, frame } = data;
        super(scene.matter.world, x, y, texture, frame);
        this.scene.add.existing(this);
        

But then i need to move my character by mouse, not dragging him. Is there any solution for this?

What excatly do you mean move by mouse not dragging him? Should it be "place the player, on click", or "click and the player should move to point", or throw on mouse release, or .... ? can you specify? do you have code that show cases abit more?

And why do you want to use two physics engines on one Object? how do you want it to react? which one should beable to override the other? Mixing arcade with matter in one game is possible. That said, use both on the same object does seem to make sense, atleast for me. Can you specify?

thanks for your comment. "click and the player should move to point" is what i want. I followed a guide on youtube to create this object, but then i want to move it by mouse, not by keyboard. All other config of Scene, Environment is set to "Matter".

Thank you for your response. how about the physics, should the arcade and the matter physics interact? Or do is the matter physics enough?

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you only want to moteh the object to the click position.
You can simply use phaser vectors (link to documentation) to create and calculate a new direction and Velocity.
Here a small Demo:


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = { 
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'matter',
        matter: {
            gravity: { y: 0 }, 
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: { create, update }, 
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click to move object')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    graphics.generateTexture('img', 20, 20);
    
    this.player = this.matter.add.image(250, 90, 'img', { restitution: 0.9 });
    this.input.on('pointerdown', moveToPoint, this);
    
    // Some objects to collide
    
    for(let idx = 0; idx < 5; idx++){
        this.matter.add.rectangle(400, 30 + 30 *idx, 10, 10, { restitution: 0.9 });
    }
    
}

function moveToPoint({x, y}){

    // Save WayPoint
    this.wayPoint = new Phaser.Math.Vector2( x, y );  
    let newVelocity = this.wayPoint
      .clone()
      .subtract(this.player)
      .setLength(10);
    
    this.player.setVelocity( newVelocity.x, newVelocity.y );
}

function update(){
   if(this.wayPoint){
       // check if near to waypoint, to prevent pass
       if(this.wayPoint.distance(this.player) <=  10){
          // clear waypoint
          this.wayPoint = null;
          this.player.setVelocity(0);
       }
   }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>




thank you so much! this is exactlys what i want. But can i ask for a little bit more, in your demo if i want my character move then stop at wherever i click, what should i add to your code

I Updated my code to stop the object, at the click position. btw.: If my answer help you please consider accepting it with the checkmark under the voting arrows. Thank you

how can you put moveToPoint outside create().  when i try to do the same as you, console show that moveToPoint is not defined.When i put moveToPoint inside Create(), my character move exactly how many pixel declare in setLength(x)

In your case since you are using a class you would have to change this.input.on('pointerdown', moveToPoint, this); to this.input.on('pointerdown', this.moveToPoint, this); if you create the moveToPoint as a class method.

thank you again. but when i do as you told, my character only move exactly how many pixel declare in setLength(x)   :((((

Well this can have many reason, since the object you are moving is a physics object, if something slows down the object, the velocity is being set to 0, or an error occurs (check the browser console) these all could be the causes. Without seeing your code it is hard to say. I would suggest , starting from my demo, adding features step by step, until you find the culprit.

i finally made it. thank you so much!
